# How to: check if a string contains another part of another string & then retrieve the matching characters

Tags: java, string, substring, contains

I know how to check if a String contains the characters of another String, what I want to know is how to check if String A contains some of String B, and then if String A does contain some of String B I would like to know what the matching characters were.

For example:

```
String stringA = "dsakldn I am String A";
String stringB = "aiwndsnkk I am String B";

//If I call this method
someMethodToFindWhichCharactersMatchInTwoStrings(stringA, stringB); 
//it would return: "I am String" as these characters are present in both Strings
```

Does anyone know of a method that I could use to achieve this result?

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem

Comment: If you mean "what is the longest string that both strings start with", you'll have to write some code. This site is not a coding service.

Comment: @JeremyFisher Thanks for the link

Comment: @Bohemian I don't need to know the longest String both Strings start with, I need to know 'how to check if String A contains some of String B' and the starting index has to be arbitrary. I didn't post code because the most similar questions to this were basically 'How to check is a String contains another String' which I know how to do, but I couldn't figure out how to get the resultant matching characters starting from arbitrary indexes so posting code for something I couldn't figure out was not possible, and posting the contains() method for the sake of it wasn't productive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is actually a tutorial page covering this on the Oracle docs:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/comparestrings.html

You need to write some code, I would suggest brushing up on your google skills too!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll accept it after I am allowed to

Comment: Cheers, but I would urge you to refine your information gathering skills, string manipulation, comparison etc, all very core programming concepts, there is tons of information out there, the SO community doesn't typically respond well when you A. Haven't demonstrated some attempt at it yourself and B. Ask questions which are covered at length in almost every programming book and website. Anyway, good luck with your project and learning Java!

Comment: I can  appreciate why the SO community wouldn't respond well to questions that seem to not have demonstrated some attempt to solve a question, but I did say in my post that I knew how to find if a String contained another String, but I couldn't figure out how to get the matching characters and it didn't seem to be productive to write out an attempt at the solution that stopped at the contains/substring methods. Next time I post on SO I'll more explicitly show what I've tried to do to solve the problem, and hopefully my googling skills will also improve in the meantime. Cheers dude